# ExtJs - GroupingView style

Tags: extjs, grid

Need to make tpl for Grouping Grid. Now I'm doing a property groupTextTpl. 
Code in it:

```
groupTextTpl : '{[values.rs[0].data["name"]]} ({[values.rs.length]} {[values.rs.length > 1 ? "Items" : "Item"]})'
```

But I want to display next to the name drop-down lists - references and to move the inscription "1 items" to the right
[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LDmGA.jpg)
How to implement it?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure if this is possible, but try wrapping the "# items" part in a HTML `<span>` tag, give it a class name and then create CSS code to align it to the right side. I.e:

```
groupTextTpl : '{[values.rs[0].data["name"]]} <span class="quantity">({[values.rs.length]} {[values.rs.length > 1 ? "Items" : "Item"]})</span>'
```

Then in the CSS you can do something like this:

```
.quantity { float: right; }
```

Hope this helps.